# Can't access Blazor app in Docker container - always listening on localhost:5000

Tags: c#, docker, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1

I've been playing around with Blazor (server side) lately and wanted to host a first app (.Net Core 3.1) in a Docker container on my Raspberry Pi 3b+.

I'm using the auto-generated Dockerfile from VS19 with some tweaks regarding the Pi architecture and the location of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster-arm32v7 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ShoppingList.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "ShoppingList.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "ShoppingList.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ShoppingList.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingList.dll"]
```

When I start a container via `docker run -p 14050:80 shoppinglist:0.1.21` the console output is

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {a885dbd5-0015-480f-8090-d67c55d5850e} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

but I can't access the website on port 14050 ("Connection failed") from my PC within the same network. However, I can access my Portainer on port 9000 - so it's not an issue with the Pi's network address.

The output's also really strange because it shouldn't listen on port 5000. When I go into the container the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` is set like `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80`. Starting the container via `docker run -p 14050:5000 shoppinglist:0.1.21` doesn't help either.

This is my Program.cs. I've tried to use the `.UseKestrel()` and `.UseUrls("http://*:80")` suggestion from the web but that doesn't work. `.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:80")` also doesn't work.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
                        .UseUrls("http://*:80");
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
                    builder.Sources.Clear();
                    builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                });
    }
```

This is my launchSettings.json - Yes, I see the 5000 ports but even if I remove or change all the `applicationUrl` entries, it'll listen on port 5000. Setting the `ServicePort` env-variable to 80 also doesn't work.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/ShoppingList",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60279",
      "sslPort": 44389
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ShoppingList": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "ShoppingList Prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

I also have no idea if the

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
```

part of the output is an issue? This never happened while debugging.

Has anyone an idea where this 5000 port is coming from and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

The problem was my Program.cs. You don't need a Host, you need a WebHost:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ShoppingList
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:80")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            });
    }
}
```

Now it's listening on port 80 and I can access it from the browser

Comment: That's too much work. Simply pass `--urls http://0.0.0.0` when calling `dotnet ShoppingList.dll` and you achieve everything without modifying the source code. Changing `ASPNETCORE_URLS` is equivalent, but you provided wrong value there.

Comment: @LexLi Setting the Dockerfile's entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingList.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0"]` doesn't work for me (with the Host version in Program.cs).